# case class - returning a different value of a parameter

Tags: scala

I have the following piece of code.

```
case class HttpMessage(key: String, message: String)

object HttpMessage {
  implicit val jsonFormat = Json.format[HttpMessage]
}
```

At this point I am using the class like

```
return HttpMessage("http.message.invalid.input", Messages("The provided input is not valid"))
```

What I want is to change the call to something like this:

```
return HttpMessage("http.message.invalid.input")
```

I am not sure how to do this as long as I can't modify the message. I don't really want to create another object to store both `val`s and construct it using another `case class` with only one parameter `key`.

The return must be

```
{
  "key": "http.message.invalid.input",
  "message": "The provided input is not valid"
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to get the message `"The provided input is not valid"` given the key `"http.message.invalid.input"` is not at all clear from your question, but presumably there is a way to do that. Given this way, you can add `def apply(key: String): HttpMessage = HttpMessage(key, getValueFromKeySomehow(key))` to `object HttpMessage` to allow calling `HttpMessage("http.message.invalid.input")`.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain what is really happening behind this?